# PANDAS: Error with .astype('datetime64[ns]') data conversion

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a set of data with date in the format: d-m-y.
Below is a sample of my raw CSV data:

| Date (d/m/y) | Transection |
| --- | --- |
| 1/2/23 | Groceries |
| 3/2/23 | Dinner |
| 5/2/23 | Lunch |
| 5/2/23 | Tea |
| ... | ... |
| 25/2/23 | Transport |
| 27/2/23 | Transport |
| ... | ... |

I used the following code to convert my 'Date' from Object to datetime64:
df.Date= df['Date'].astype('datetime64[ns]')

Upon checking the dtype, I can confirm that the datatype has been converted to datetime64[ns].

**ISSUE FACING:**

| Date(Y-d-m) | Transection |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-02 | Groceries |
| 2023-03-02 | Dinner |
| 2023-05-02 | Lunch |
| 2023-01-02 | Tea |
| ... | ... |
| 2023-02-25 | Transport |
| 2023-02-27 | Transport |
| ... | ... |

Notice how the data has been misinterpreted. Single digit dates such as 1st, 3rd, 5th has been interpreted as months. Instead of 1st February 2023, it changed to 2nd January 2023. But once the date goes into the double digits, it is not misinterpreted. 25th February 2023 is the same in both tables.

Hoping someone have a way to fix this issue. Your help is greatly appreciated!! Thank you in advance!!

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may specify the date format when parsing the column as date.

```
import pandas as pd

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%y')
```

Do see this for more date formats: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior